# Connect linkedList in java

Tags: java, arrays

I hava list of LinkedList and I want to make (unable to modified) One connected LinkedList .
and not change the original linkedLists.

```
 LinkedLists<String> a=new LinkedList<String>();
 LinkedLists<String> b=new LinkedList<String>();
 LinkedLists<String> c=new LinkedList<String>();

 a.add("as");
 a.add("sa");
 a.add("bb");
 b.add("as");
 b.add("sa");
 c.add("bb");
 c.add("d");
 c.add("ya");
```

the new LinkedList contain ya d bb sa as bb sa as

so I want to make one Linked List.I preffer Not copy the items casue this consume memory.
Only connect theme for go all over the items not to modified the items.

Thanks!

Comment: I dont want to duplicate... Only to represent theme as one linkedList..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Collections#unmodifiableList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29)

Sample code:

```
    LinkedList<String> a = new LinkedList<String>();

    a.add("as");
    a.add("sa");
    a.add("bb");

    a.add("as");
    a.add("sa");

    a.add("bb");
    a.add("d");
    a.add("ya");

    List<String> b = Collections.unmodifiableList(a.subList(0, 3));
    List<String> c = Collections.unmodifiableList(a.subList(5, 8));


    b.set(0, "aa"); // not allowed
    c.add("zz"); // not allowed

    a.set(6, "zz"); // allowed and List c is also updated.
```

Comment: Ok but how I connect them? I want to make a value thate represent those lists connected not create new ellements.

Comment: Let me modify my post to make it clear to your.

Comment: I understand this.But the I dont want to put the elemants in the same LinkedList. This is my problem.

Comment: @user3160197 now not clear to me. What you want?

Comment: here all the List are connected but you can't modify the List `b` and `c` and changes in List `a` will reflect in both the list also if in range.

Comment: I want let say 4 linkedList that I can change every LinkedList and control Every Linked list. but all thoes linkedList will have represent by new linkedList that contain the itemes of those LinkedList one by one..

Comment: create a new List and add all the 4 List in it. Its so simple. where is the problem in this design? Memory issue right?

Comment: Yes. I think that add create new and not contain pointer.
So if I use add or addAll this multiple the number of cells.

Comment: If i think about it again. the duplicate is only for the pointers.
This is so bad?

Answer (score 0):

Try subclassing List. Here's a quick example I put together below. It's largely incomplete but you'll get the idea.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Experiment {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        LinkedList<String> a = new LinkedList<String>();
        LinkedList<String> b = new LinkedList<String>();
        LinkedList<String> c = new LinkedList<String>();

        a.add("as");
        a.add("sa");
        a.add("bb");
        b.add("as");
        b.add("sa");
        c.add("bb");
        c.add("d");
        c.add("ya");

        MyLinkedList<String> list = new MyLinkedList<String>();
        list.add(a);
        list.add(b);
        list.add(c);

        for (String s : list) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    private static class MyLinkedList<T> extends LinkedList<T> {
        private List<List<T>> lists = new LinkedList<List<T>>();

        public void add(LinkedList<T> list) {
            lists.add(list);
        }

        @Override
        public Iterator<T> iterator() {
            return new MyLinkedIterator<T>(lists);
        }
    }

    private static class MyLinkedIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
        private List<List<T>> lists;
        private int listIndex = 0;
        private int currentIndex = 0;
        private T next;

        public MyLinkedIterator(List<List<T>> lists) {
            this.lists = lists;
        }

        public boolean hasNext() {
            if (listIndex >= lists.size()) return false;

            List<T> list = lists.get(listIndex);
            if (currentIndex >= list.size()) {
                currentIndex = 0;
                listIndex++;

                return hasNext();
            }

            next = list.get(currentIndex++);

            return true;
        }

        public T next() {
            return next;
        }

        public void remove() {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
 LinkedList<String> a=new LinkedList<String>();
 LinkedList<String> b=new LinkedList<String>();
 LinkedList<String> c=new LinkedList<String>();

 a.add("as");
 a.add("sa");
 a.add("bb");
 b.add("as");
 b.add("sa");
 c.add("bb");
 c.add("d");
 c.add("ya");

 LinkedList<String> unionList = new LinkedList<String>();

 unionList.addAll(a);
 unionList.addAll(b);
 unionList.addAll(c);

 LinkedList<String> unmodifiableUnion = Collections.unmodifiableList(unionList);
```

It uses `addAll()` to add all lists into a new one and returns an unmodifiable list from it using `Collections.unmodifiableList()`

#### Update

If memory consumption is your problem, the standard JDK is not enough. You will have to implement your own or use an existing one.

To implement your own you can usa a `LinkedList<List<T>>` to store your linked lists and implement the `List` interface. mprivat started an implementation for you.

To use an existing one, you could use:

- [Trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/): it is considered really good and fast if no fastest with least memory consumption, at least that is what I have observed in my usages of it.
- [this implementation](https://code.google.com/p/singly-linked-list/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/datastructure/SinglyLinkedList.java): it is a singly linked list so it consumes less memory and has a `merge` method that will merge 2 linked lists using their *"pointers"* as you would expect.

Comment: **items cause this consume memory** What about this factor? you have created a new `List`.

Comment: Maybe this copy only the pointers so its not so bad???

Comment: Updated the answer to address the memory requirement. As for the `addAll`, it will transform the list into an array and then add each element of the array to the linked list so it is not memory efficient.